# Youtube metadata and opengraph tags

Tags: dom, web-scraping, youtube, facebook-opengraph, awesomium

I made a little software to help me to manage a collection of links to web pages. I enter an URL, it reads all meta and extracts title, short description, link to the video alone when adequate, and a preview picture. Part of the properties were 'og:' ones, but 'twitter:' ones are often available too in most of the websites I'm bookmarking. I'm using all of this to create a small preview like facebook does.

It used to run fine on youtube videos, but for some days, youtube has its new design. It also sets a bunch of variables at one time through a big json object, which I'm painly trying to extract using awesomium DOM exploration functions, but I'm asking myself: am I doing things wrong ? Is there a new way of making those properties available, different from opengraph ? A new standard ? Copying a youtube link into facebook still creates a well formed preview, did FB have to code a specific parser ? variable names in youtube source code start with yt, so I suspect it's not a generic mecanism.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance (and sorry for my English).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the user agent to "facebookexternalhit/1.1" in order to have the OpenGraph metas in the dom.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616889/3319858