# Finding Open Graph tags on youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm working on a Tampermonkey script to hide related videos on youtube if the `og:video:tag` contains "League of Legends".

When I use the Open Graph Debugger ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsbmIEmc5l58%26t%3D10m23s)) it find many tags (`og:video:url`, `og:video:width`, `og:video:tag`, ...) but when I search in the DOM I am unable to find any of these elements.

I've tried disabling all my extensions, from a clean profile, from incognito as well as using an Open Graph Extension still I can't find the tags.

Some other attempts:

```
$('[property="og:type"]') => null.

document.getElementsByTagName('meta') => two unrelated tags.
```

Answer (score 7):

YouTube video source contains those tags only if the `userAgent` is

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

or (I used this in my test)

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1
```

You can test these by adding a new device to DevTools with those user agents. I am not sure you want to use these tags, but you have two options:

- If there is backend processer for finding these tags, you can switch the user agent to appropriate one there.
- If you're working on a browser extension, you should set up a proxy that does the above for you. Send the video permalink and return an object of tags.

Comment: Indeed, the User-Agent header is the key. However it doesn't have to be Facebook's. The following one works too: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MySuperTool)"